Updating Three.js to the latest version: gray screen no error
I’m trying to update this program (originally written with Three.js r88) to work with the latest version of Three.js.
Original code: https://codepen.io/shubniggurath/pen/OEeMOd
My code: https://codepen.io/jfvwblgr-the-sasster/pen/ByBzRex
The program runs without any errors, but all I see is a gray screen. Did I miss anything when updating the code for the newer Three.js version?
I’ve made the following changes so far:

Switched to importing Three.js via ES6 modules.
Replaced var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(2, 2); with var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2);.
Renamed the sample variable in the fragment shader to sampleCoord since sample is now a reserved keyword.


Links don't work.

Links are fixed now.
